# actionscript matrix rotate() and DisplayObject.rotation property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

It seems applying matrix rotate() to a display object is different from DisplayObject.rotation. What I want is using the matrix.rotate() to get the same result of using rect.rotation = 45. But the actual result is not the same.

Code example:

```
public class Demo extends Sprite {
    public function Demo() {
       testRotation();
    }

    private function testRotation():void {
        var rect:Shape = new Shape();
        rect.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
        rect.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
        rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
        rect.graphics.endFill();
        rect.x = 100;
        rect.y = 100;
        addChild(rect);
        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        trace(matrix);
        matrix.rotate(Math.PI*45/180);
        rect.transform.matrix = matrix;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what "Does not work."  What are the effects you want?  What are you getting?  I also don't think this question has anything to do w/ the Flex Framework, so I'm not sure if that tag is appropriate.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, I had rephrase my question, thanks for your advise

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that *rotate* method rotates coordination around top-left corner(0,0) as the pic shows.[image]

solution:

```
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(-50,-50)// Translate to center of square
matrix.rotate(Math*45/180); //rotate 45 degrees
matrix.translate(rect.x+150, rect.y+150)
rect.transform.matrix = matrix
```